# Spring boot application cant access other services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

Hello stack**overflow**

1. I have kubernetes setup on premises with one master and one slave.
2. I have deployed two spring boot application viz i] Eureka server ii] Zuul Server, both the services are on same namespace(default),different pods.(Both the applications are deployed using docker images)
3. The Eureka server is deployed successfully and running.
4. My Zuul server registers itself with eureka on startup by using the url of eureka server.
5. But when i deploy the zuul server i get connection refused while connecting to eureka server.

   a. I can ping the eureka server from the pod in which zuul is running, but from withing the spring boot application it says connection refused.

   b. I am using service name for service discovery in kubernetes, which i have tested in the shell of the zuul's pod.

   P.S. I think the problem is that the java application is being blocked by the system from accessing outside resource.

Please can any one provide any solution or hint about what i am doing wrong or missing.